# SQL - Flagging a most recent entry by date

Tags: sql, date, max

I have the following data.

```
Clientid  Accountype  Dateapplied
1         Current     01/01/2018
1         Savings     03/01/2018
1         Current     17/01/2018
2         Current     01/04/2018
2         Current     15/04/2018
3         Savings     13/04/2018
3         Savings     15/04/2018
3         Current     14/04/2018
```

How do I select the latest dated entry in here per Client where the `Accountype = Current`. Basically I want to be able to flag to latest entry per client so when I can work out the select I would set a new field as True.
 So results I want to bring back are:

```
Clientid  Accountype  Dateapplied
1         Current     17/01/2018
2         Current     15/04/2018
3         Current     14/04/2018
```

I've tried also sort of grouping by ClientID then selecting using max but whatever I try I can't pick out the latest one per clientid. Should be simple but racking my brains at it.

So tried things like this but not working. Appreciated if help anyone.

```
select Dateapplied,Clientid, Accountype  
from Clienttable t1
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1
     FROM Clienttable t2

     WHERE Accountype  = 'Current'
     and  t2.Clientid = t1.X_Clientid

     GROUP BY t2.Clientid,
              t2.Dateapplied
     HAVING t1.Dateapplied= MAX(t2.Dateapplied))
```

Comment: You've tagged SQL Server and MySQL here. Which RDBMS are you *really using? SQL Server and MySQL are 2 different problems. Please update your tags with only the correct RDBMS.

Comment: *whatever I try I can't pick out the latest one per clientid* what data type is `Dateapplied`? I guess it's not date.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use subquery. Just get the max(dateapplied)

```
SELECT ClientId, AccountType, max(dateapplied) dateapplied
from clienttable
where accountType = 'Current'
Group by ClientId, AccountType
```